# Angular - converting from Observable<any> to Observable<CalendarEventUserConnection>

Tags: angular, observable

I use this service method in my Angular 5 application:

```
createDateUserConnection(calendarEventUserConnection: CalendarEventUserConnection): Observable<any> {
    let creationIndex: number = 0;
    let url: string = environment.apiEndpoint + 'calendareventuserconnections/calendareventuserconnection/' + calendarEventUserConnection.calendarEvent.id + '/' + creationIndex;
    return this.http.post(url, calendarEventUserConnection, this.options);
}
```

I want to convert the return type of this method from `Observable<any>` to `Observable<CalendarEventUserConnection>`. Is there a way of doing it in a simple way?

Comment: Are you using Http  (deprecated) or HttpClient ? I thought HttpClient handled the cast for you

Comment: What is the error if you replace `Observable<any>` with `Observable<CalendarEventUserConnection>`?

Comment: Then I get: **Die Eigenschaft "calendarEvent" fehlt im Typ "Response".**

Comment: How about `return this.http.post<CalendarEventUserConnection>(url, ...`